# Is there a way to re-arranging the order of blocks (flex) in Css

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I wanna change the order of my elements (divs flex displayed) in mobile, the initial structure is already done but i found a difficulties to customize it to satisfy my needs in mobile, any help ?

[image]

Comment: Its possible easily if you could arrange all three elements inside the same flex container.

Comment: Yeah i know, the probleme is that the initial layout is already finished so i can't change it again

Comment: Please post enough code in the question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does the red indicate the same container element in both layouts? Because if so, the only way you're going to turn **Element 3** from a sibling of that container until a child of that container is via javascript. (Which is straightforward enough if that's what you need).

Comment: @Rounin yes it's the same container, and it's the main problem in my solution,

Comment: @Michael_B the code won't explain nothing in my situation as the image above :)

Comment: @hazam120 the code will explain what you've attempted so far so that we don't feel like were doing your work for you.

Comment: @Michael_B you are right, i'm sorry, just i'm sure now that i can't solve my prob using just the flex technics, only Jquery can.

Comment: FYI, the "flex" tag refers to Adobe Flex.  For CSS questions, use "flexbox".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key issue here is that the flexbox `order` property, while powerful, can't turn a sibling element into a child element. Only javascript can do that.

Here is one approach that works using CSS flexbox and CSS `@media` queries but which employs javascript (rather than the flexbox `order` property) to move `.div3` across the DOM, so that it becomes a child element of `.child-container`:

```js
var narrowScreen = window.matchMedia("(max-width:600px)");
var screenIsNarrow = false;

var parentContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('parent-container')[0];
var childContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('child-container')[0];

var div1 = document.getElementsByClassName('div1')[0];
var div2 = document.getElementsByClassName('div2')[0];
var div3 = document.getElementsByClassName('div3')[0];


function checkScreenWidth() {

    if ((narrowScreen.matches) && (screenIsNarrow === false)) {
        childContainer.insertBefore(div3, div1);
        childContainer.insertBefore(div2, div3);
        screenIsNarrow = true;
    }

    else if ((!narrowScreen.matches) && (screenIsNarrow === true)) {
        childContainer.insertBefore(div1, div2);
        parentContainer.insertBefore(div3, childContainer);
        parentContainer.insertBefore(childContainer, div3);
        screenIsNarrow = false;
    } 

}


window.addEventListener('resize', checkScreenWidth, false);
window.addEventListener('load', checkScreenWidth, false);
```

```css
.parent-container {
display: flex;
width: 90vw;
min-height: 200px;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 200px;
text-align: center;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.child-container {
display: flex;
flex: 1 0 74%;
padding: 24px 4vw;
margin-right: 1vw;
background-color: rgb(191,191,191);
}

.div1, .div2 {
flex: 1 1 45%;
margin: 3px 0.5vw;
background-color: rgb(83,83,83);
}

.div3 {
flex: 1 0 24%;
background-color: rgb(127,127,127);
}


@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {

.child-container {
display: inline-block;
}

.div1, .div2, .div3 {
margin: 6px;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">

    <div class="child-container">
        <div class="div1">One</div>
        <div class="div2">Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="div3">Three</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Rounin, i figured out a way doing it with jquery, using appendTo() and then re ordering with css using the property order ;)